# I am getting encoding issue and ensure_ascii=False issue while writing to a csv file

Tags: python, csv, encoding, non-ascii-characters, iso-8859-1

I have list of dictionaries and I loaded those dictionaries from json files. I stored those json files with my code as following

```
import json
data = {Some Json}
with open('test.json','w',encoding='ISO-8859-1') as file:
   json.dump(data,file,indent=4,ensure_ascii=False)
```

When I use `ensure_ascii` it stores correctly. I have German characters which only can be stored using `ISO-8859-1`. The `utf-8` or anything is not working correctly.
Here are some characters

```
Größe
ä
```

But the issue came when I tried to store the list of dictionaries into a csv file this does not work.
When I try to save a csv file from it as I cannot `ensure_ascii=False` there as it only uses with `json.dump()`
so I do not get characters correctly in csv. What I got in csv was replacement character `��` 
Here is what i tried to store csv file

```
csv_file = "data.csv"
with open(csv_file, mode="w", newline="",encoding='ISO-8859-1',errors='replace') as file:
     writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=mainList[0].keys())
     writer.writeheader()
     for row in mainList:
         writer.writerow(row)
```

So I should get words Größe but i get Gr��e in csv file.
I tried searching on google,etc but didn't get any solution.

If you can help I appreciate it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/)

Comment: JSON must always be UTF8. It's the standard. Remove the `encoding=` parameter entirely. In Python 3 [it's the default](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type)

Answer (score 0):

This script saves the json special characters fine at my side:

```py
import json

jsonfile = {"Größe": "ä"}

with open('test.json','w',encoding='utf8') as file:
   json.dump(jsonfile,file,indent=4,ensure_ascii=False)
```